# Show Jomsocial registration form directly on frontpage?

Tags: forms, joomla1.5, registration

i use joomla 1.5 within jomsocial login. Right now, when users click on register button, page reload and show a registration form.
How can i show this form directly on frontpage ( like on facebook registration ) with a sign up button after?
Thanks. Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use {loadposition MODULEPOSITION} in a article on your homepage. That will include a module in your article.

A better way is to modify your template with a new module position.